# Нейронная сеть для небольшой консольной игры на питоне

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

я написал на питоне небольшую простую консольную игру по типу "60 seconds". Там нужно прожить 365 дней и в конце(если ты, конечно, доживешь) выводятся результаты(сколько потратил денег, сколько съел еды..). Чтобы не прогонять все это ручками, мне пришла в голову идея написать нейронку, которая будет выживать в моей игре. Только вот в написании нейронок я полный ноль, до этого ни разу не писал. Не могли бы вы подсказать какая именно нейронная сеть мне нужна(чтобы там были эпохи и, еще, чтобы когда она делала правильные действия я ее "награждал", я где-то слышал про такую нейронку, которая методом "кнута и пряника" работает). И если у вас есть ссылки, то можете тоже их прикрепить. Спасибо большое

Comment: Чтобы не писать с нуля можно использовать https://www.tensorflow.org/. Думаете сколько у вас будет входных данных (например деньги, еда и тд), потом подбираете методом тыка кол-во скрытых слоев и еще слой с результатом (например если нужно считать ходы, то например 4 выхода - идти вверх, вниз и тд). Вот. А обучать можно с помощью генетического алгоритма. Делаете несколько ботов, выбираете двух лучших, берёте их веса и ищете среднее. Создаете новую партию ботов уже с этими весами (но эти веса надо мутировать перед созданием новых ботов, чтобы они не были все одинаковые).

Comment: Хороший пример для начала на игре [flappy bird с tensorflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdUNkwXx-I4) (правда там слишком упрощено)

Comment: Думаю, вам не нужна нейронная сеть в этом случае.  Вполне подойдут алгоритмч машинного обучения с подкреплением.  И проще и самому понятнее, что происходит.
Рекомендую книгу:   Обучение с подкреплением  на PyTorch:  сборник рецептов

Comment: Забыл добавить, что лучшего надо выбирать по какому-то значению - к примеру счёту игры. Но тут надо подумать как правильно его считать.

Comment: Спасибо большое всем

Comment: Лучше использовать более высокоуровневую библиотеку `Keras`, она сейчас штатно входит прямо в `Tensorflow`. Для начинающих её интерфейс гораздо проще.